# A circular reference error with ASMX with linked table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, asmx

I have the below code for an `ASMX service` in a Web Application. Attempting to get the data in XML format. I have removed some data for clarity

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CompanyServices
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class CompanyServices: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public List<Product> GetData(int companyId, int custId)
        {
          return ProductService.GetCompanyData(companyId, custId).ToList();
        }
```

In debug mode all runs but i keep getting the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type Company
```

So i created the same type and had a for each loop around it similar to

```
foreach (Product p in ProductService.GetCompanyData(companyId, custId).ToList())
{
  Product newProd = new Product
  newProd.Name = p.Name;
  newProd.Department = p.Department;
}
```

This worked until i added Department in, which is linked to another table (of Departments)

Googled around but no idea whats causing this or how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular reference means you have an object `a` that references `b` (e.g. `a.B = b`) but somehow `b` references `a` back (like `b.A = a`).

Unfortunately, it's not always that two objects point each to another. Your chain that leads to circularity can be longer (like `product` points to another `product` that points to `department` that points back to `product`).

Most of the times the root cause is that your service exposes your raw Entity Framework (or other ORM) objects that are joined using parent-child relations. Because ORM navigation properties are lazily loaded, anytime you have a `product`, it has its parent (like `product.Department`) but a `department` has the `Products` property that points back to products and one of the products is the very same product you already visited at the beginning. There's your cycle.

The solution is to create another set of classes, the DTO classes, where you maintain only one-way navigation properties. So for example, a `ProductDTO` has its parent, the `DepartmentDTO` but the `DepartmentDTO` intentionally **lacks** the `IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Products` property.

This way the serializer that follows your navigation properties stops at some point as there are no cycles. Your service exposes these DTO classes

```
[WebMethod]
public List<ProductDTO> GetData(int companyId, int custId)
{
   return ProductService.GetCompanyData(companyId, custId).ToDTO();
}
```

Comment: So ProductDTO is a new class with ALL the same properties as the Product class? Also how did you add the extension to the return line of code?

Comment: Yes, a new class but you pay attention to **not to have** two-way navigation properties. The extension is just an example, convert domain instances to DTO instances any way you want.